# How to update the data according to the user selection in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change the data according to the user selection in a list in real time. How would i suppose to achieve this task?

For example:

if the user selects the below information.

> How would you like to give us a feedback?

```
<select>
<option>Comment here</option>
<option>Mail us</option>
<option>Fill the survey</option>
</select>
```

And if the user selects the first one a comment box should appear below it, if second the mailto link should appear and if the last one then some fields about the survey should be displayed.

Comment: what type of data, is this db-related?

Comment: `db=database` - so, is it? or is it irrelevant?

Comment: You need some [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) on AJAX :)

Comment: Yeah, that' about collecting the feedback after the providing the customer services & it was yeah, irrelevant!

Comment: I had to ask. You wouldn't believe the amount of questions we see where, people ask about this type of question, only to turn out that in the end, it was all about databases. Your question, as far as I'm concerned, was unclear. You didn't mention anything about JS etc. Just tagged as `php` and `html`.

Comment: Umm yeah. I can understand that. Glad you asked! :)

Comment: I'm glad you found you found your solution, *cheers*. Should you post another question in the future, including any relevant information you deem as being relevant, will help everyone and provide you with a concrete solution. After all, it's all about finding a "solution" ;-) *Welcome to Stack* :-)

Comment: Yeah, sure I'd and welcome to the family! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple solution

```
<select id="my_select">
<option value="comment">Comment here</option>
<option value="mail">Mail us</option>
<option value="survey">Fill the survey</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initially hide all three boxes
    $('#my_select').on('change',function(){
        var hasval = $(this).val();
        if(hasval == 'comment'){
           // show your comment box and hide rest of two
        } else if(hasval == 'mail'){
           // show your mail and hide rest of two
        } else {
           // survey form and vice versa
        }
    });
});
```